# Android Webview Unknown Error

Tags: android, webview, android-logcat

I have made an app that uses `WebView`. It works, however, the `LogCat` produces this error:

```
03-27 10:36:35.830: E/eglCodecCommon(1466): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
```

I understand that 0x0 is an unknown error type (in Linux command), but how can I fix this?
My `Java` code is:

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private WebView edlineWebView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar1;
    private String currentUrl;
    private boolean exitConfirmation;
    private BroadcastReceiver completeReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Resources res = context.getResources();
            Toast.makeText(context, res.getString(R.string.download_complete), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS));
        }
    };

    final Activity activity = this;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (edlineWebView.copyBackForwardList().getCurrentIndex() > 0) {
            edlineWebView.goBack();
        }    
        else {
            if (exitConfirmation) {
                super.onBackPressed();
                return;
            }

            this.exitConfirmation = true;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Press the back key again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    exitConfirmation=false;                       
                }
            }, 2000);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        edlineWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1); 
        progressBar1 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        String url = "http://www.edline.net/";

        edlineWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        edlineWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        edlineWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3");
        edlineWebView.loadUrl(url);
        edlineWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
                MimeTypeMap mtm = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
                DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(url);
                String fileName = downloadUri.getLastPathSegment();
                int pos = 0;

                if ((pos = contentDisposition.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf("filename=")) >= 0) {
                    fileName = contentDisposition.substring(pos + 9);
                    pos = fileName.lastIndexOf(";");
                    if (pos > 0) {
                        fileName = fileName.substring(0, pos - 1);
                    }
                }

                String fileExtension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, fileName.length()).toLowerCase();
                String mimeType = mtm.getMimeTypeFromExtension(fileExtension);
                Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri);
                request.setTitle(fileName);
                request.setDescription(url);
                request.setMimeType(mimeType);  
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir( Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory( Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).mkdirs();
                downloadManager.enqueue(request);
            }
        });

        currentUrl = url;
        edlineWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() 
        {  
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) 
            {  
                if (progress<100)
                {
                    progressBar1.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
                }
                else if (progress==100)
                {
                    progressBar1.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);              
                }
                progressBar1.setProgress(progress);  
            }
        });

        edlineWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                currentUrl = edlineWebView.getUrl();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(completeReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        IntentFilter completeFilter = new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);
        registerReceiver(completeReceiver, completeFilter);
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.goto_browser:
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(currentUrl));
            startActivity(i);

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: If your app doesn't crash and you just see this error in the logcat, you're fine. Your code probably isn't to blame for the error. More than likely it is an error in the page you are loading. The WebView throws those errors all the time but they won't affect your app.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my case, I loaded a site which contains an Image slider. The logcat produces this same error code when the slider changes the images. I assume this happens, because the webpage computes the size of the screen of my device. I am just guessing, because it's from gl:

```
05-03 10:15:25.149: E/eglCodecCommon(5081): **** ERROR unknown type 0x1 (glSizeof,73)
```