# Can not access local IP on webview loadUrl

Tags: android

I tried to create an android app with webview, but there was an error because it could not access my IP ex: 192.168.1.100 can not even access localhost also by using IP 10.0.2.2, my computer is connected with proxy with IP 192.168.8.80, what is the problem? .. I have also added the uses-permission INTERNET but still error ...

Comment: post your logcat here

Comment: Post some more details..

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103463/how-to-access-the-local-host-server-with-web-view-in-android

Comment: logcat message `07-27 02:53:34.270 6762-6762/com.irwandevelop.webview E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x20063 (glSizeof,73)`

Comment: check this for your understanding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22685375/android-webview-unknown-error